# Conditional expectation of the probability that a prior parameter is greater than some value

Tags: bayesian, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, conditional-expectation, integral

I am working in a Bayesian setting where I have a prior $p \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$. For reasons that don't really matter, I'm later defining a new parameter, call it $C$, which is the probability that the prior parameter is greater than some cutoff point. For simplicity, I'm starting with $C=\mathbb{P}(p>0.5)$. Obviously $C$ is determined by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from the prior and (according to the Wikipedia entry for the CDF of the beta distribution) can be written as $C=1-I_{0.5}(\alpha, \beta)$ where $I$ is the regularized incomplete beta function.

Now, what I really want to do is compute $\mathbb{E}[C|C<\alpha^*]$ for some arbitrary $\alpha^* \in (0,1)$. So far, my attempt at this looks like:
$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[C|C<\alpha^*] = \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(C<\alpha^*)} \int_{0}^{\alpha^*} C f_C(C) dC. 
\end{align}$

The part where I then get confused is $f_C(C)$, which is the distribution of the probability $\mathbb{P}(p>0.5)$ where $p$ itself is beta distributed. Can anyone  help me understand how to proceed? Is this the density of a CDF and therefore uniformly distributed? I think my problem is that there are a lot of parameters floating around and I'm having trouble keeping them straight. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this simply truncated distribution?

Comment: I think you're right that I'm truncating the random variable C by specifying that $C<\alpha^*$, which leads to the definition of the conditional expectation. But I still don't know the distribution of C in the first place. Can you elaborate?